# If you went to the moon, wouldn't you experience space time curvature?

Tags: space-travel, gravity, spacetime-dimensions

[image]

I am trying to better understand the relationship between space and time. Did astronauts experience an "acceleration of time" when not under the influence of an external massive object like the Earth or the Moon?

Does "time" "flow" faster in space?

Comment: Why asking this question on Worldbuilding and not on Physics SE? It is pure physics.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, absolutely, but the diagram you include has greatly exaggerated the scale of the curvature to make it more noticeable, and in practice it’s completely undetectable except using the most sensitive atomic clocks. See [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/If-you-place-a-clock-on-Earth-and-one-on-the-Moon-after-100-hours-will-there-be-any-difference?share=1) — the difference in the rate of flow of time between Earth and Moon is about 6E-12. So if you’re on the Moon for 10 days, you’ll experience about 5 microseconds more than someone on Earth.

Comment: Yes - absolutely. We call the space time curvature "gravity" :-)

Comment: For a (more or less) everyday example, GPS satellite signals must be corrected for time differences due to the lesser gravity at their orbiting altitudes - about 5 parts in 10^-10: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System#Relativity